# Can I upgrade either Windows (bootcamp partition) and OS X independently of each other on the same hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp

I am getting ready to reformat my Bootcamp partition and installed Windows 7 Ultimate over Windows 7 Professional.

The thing is, down the line I probably need to reformat and reinstall OS X.

Can I reformat/reinstall OS X and not loose my bootcamp partition/Windows install?

Comment: Is there a reason you're reformatting to upgrade from Win 7 Pro to Win 7 Ultimate instead of using the builtin upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They're on separate partitions so you can upgrade them independently just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no trouble doing that at all. Just be sure to reformat and reinstall each respective OS to the correct partition.